# Is my SSD broken?

Tags: ssd

```
/bin/ls: cannot access cache-zch-5666-cache.txt: Input/output error
/bin/ls: cannot access cache-zch-4970-cache.txt: Input/output error
/bin/ls: cannot access cache-zch-4782-cache.txt: Input/output error
./   cache-zch-4782-cache.txt  cache-zch-5666-cache.txt
../  cache-zch-4970-cache.txt
root@host [/home2/investgr1/public_html/hello/cache/zch]# rm *
rm: cannot remove `cache-zch-4782-cache.txt': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `cache-zch-4970-cache.txt': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `cache-zch-5666-cache.txt': Input/output error
root@host [/home2/investgr1/public_html/hello/cache/zch]#
**
```

What does input/output error mean>?

How do I make sure that it's broken. So far only a few file. I am wondering if something more profound happen

Is there a way to prove to my provider that it's indeed a problematic SSD?

Also, can I try to just reformat the disk?

I am concern that there is a bad sector on that disk.

My host said:

> We will only replace the drive if we can identify a problem with it.
>   The permissions error you encountered is not an indicator of a failed
>   drive.
>
> If you require any further assistance feel free to update this ticket.

Comment: What does `dmesg | tail` say?

Answer (score 0):

Those input/output errors almost definitely indicate some sort of hardware failure.

Chances are that either your disk or RAM are failing. Stop writing to the SSD
immediately. If necessary, backup the data on the SSD. It may be prudent to use
a tool such as [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/). Then [test
your RAM](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/memtest86.htm).

Comment: How to test that the hard disk is okay?

Comment: How to proof that it's indeed hardware failure.

Comment: You can use [`smartctl`](http://blogs.nologin.es/slopez/archives/33-Checking-the-health-of-your-SSD-from-GNULinux.html) to check for disk errors.